# How to bind image source to file object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two elements one file and another image

`<input type='file' id='myfile' />

  <img  id='myImg' >`

When i select image using file browse, my image object should be updated with the selected image
How can i achieve this using angular?

Answer (score 4):

Use FileReader for this. For example:

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <img ng-src="{{loadedFile}}" alt="" />
    <input type="file" value="load" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileLoaded(this)" />
</div>
```

**code**

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.fileLoaded = function (e) {
        var tgt = e.target || window.event.srcElement,
            files = tgt.files,
            fileReader;

        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function () {

                $scope.loadedFile = fileReader.result;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        } else {
            // Not supported
        }
    };
});
```

---

[Look fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-flow`

Check out Gallery upload from here http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/

Hope this helps you!

Comment: @debianmaster: I think the directive ``ng-flow`` that I have suggested should solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript way of doing this is on  onchange event is

```js
var file = event.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

I need it in Angular